Rename files with non-Latin characters
I have Kubuntu 22.04. Is there a program, script, etc. in *buntu that can rename all files in a folder with non-Latin characters to their Latin equivalent? For example, I have a folder that contains files with names like:
Andúril
Dúnedain
Éomer

and I need to rename them to:
Anduril
Dunedain
Eomer


What's the Latin equivalent of ξ, ω, θ, æ? Do you only and exclusively have letters from the ASCII set with accents, or can it be more varied?

@terdon or even "ü" - is it "u" or "ue"? That depends on language and even context, and of course the preferred substitution in German doesn't even maintain the number.of characters.

@ChrisH: Even worse: it may or may not preserve the number of characters, depending on how the ü glyph is normalized. The ü glyph can be written as either as U+00FC Latin small character u with diaeresis (ü) or as U+0075 Latin small letter u followed by U+0308 Combining diaeresis (ü). In the latter case, the number of characters would be maintained, though not the number of columns, glyphs, or grapheme clusters.

@JörgWMittag You're right. By "characters" I was referring to graphemes/columns as the user would see, but of course it can also be interpreted in other ways.  Other languages using the diaeresis map to single characters (e.g. Welsh at least informally - and even in English "naïve" is dated but valid)

Off the top of my head, Perl's Text::Unidecode module can do this (technically it will attempt to transliterate Unicode characters outside of ASCII's range into a suitable ASCII replacement):

The representation is almost always an attempt at transliteration-- i.e., conveying, in Roman letters, the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system.

sudo apt install libtext-unidecode-perl

Most conveniently, you could combine this with the Perl-based rename utility and do the following:
rename -u utf8 -n 'BEGIN {use Text::Unidecode}; unidecode($_)' *

This will perform a dry-run (no filename will be changed but the result of the substitution for each file will be displayed); if you're happy with the result, remove the -n flag:
rename -u utf8 'BEGIN {use Text::Unidecode}; unidecode($_)' *

The -u option is important as it will tell rename / Perl to treat filenames as UTF-8-encoded strings.
% ls -la
totale 36
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 32768 ott 15 19:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 42 user user  4096 ott 15 20:01 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 ott 15 19:53 Andúril
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 ott 15 19:53 Dúnedain
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 ott 15 19:53 Éomer
% rename -u utf8 'BEGIN {use Text::Unidecode}; unidecode($_)' *
% ls -la
totale 36
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 32768 ott 15 20:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 42 user user  4096 ott 15 20:01 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 ott 15 19:53 Anduril
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 ott 15 19:53 Dunedain
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 ott 15 19:53 Eomer


I wonder how this handles collisions, e.g. if you have Andúril and Andüril in the same folder - I'd expect a silent overwrite with terminal tools

@ChrisH If you're wondering whether rename will figure out collisions before they happen: no, it won't. But by default rename's behavior is like mv's with -n / --no-clobber, so the one who sorts first will be renamed and the one who sorts last will be left as-is, with a message printed to STDERR

My usual go-to for this type of things is a program called detox. It’s packaged on Ubuntu (and most other Linux distros) in a package of the same name.
The default behavior of the command will not actually entirely do what you want, as the primary purpose of the command is to get rid of shell metacharacters in file names, and the current version has shifted away from collapsing things down to ASCII since that is by definition lossy and modern filesystems have no issues with UTF-8 filenames.
However, on Debian, Ubuntu, and many other distros, it still includes the old translation tables that do essentially exactly what you want. In particular:
detox -r -s utf_8-only .

Will do exactly what you’re asking for, recursively for the current working directory. Dropping the -only on the third argument will make it also transform characters that would be interpreted by the shell (and thus normally need escaped on the command line) into safe equivalents (usually _).
